# Proof of lagrange inversion of taylor series

Tags: analysis, taylor-expansion, lagrange-inversion

is there a proof for the lagrange inversion of taylor series? The formula is given in 
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange_inversion_theorem#Theorem_statement

The proof cannot be found in the sources provided, nor in the wolfram reference, nor anywhere i have searched on the internet (including lagrange's original paper). I have searched many books on analysis and still couldnt find a proof for the formula. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Whittaker & Watson, *A Course of Modern Analysis*. Section 7.3 is about relevant expansions, with Lagrange inversion on [page 133](https://books.google.com/books?id=ULVdGZmi9VcC&pg=PA133) in a somewhat different form.